# Can't log into MariaDB/MySQL after install (RedHat) using mysql -u root -p

Tags: mysql, linux, installation, redhat, mariadb

I have run a binary install of MariaDB, i will provide the following commands that i used.
(Forgive me I have a fairly basic level of mysql so I have annotated with my understanding of what the commands do).

Added group called mysql

```
shell> groupadd mysql 
shell> useradd -r -g mysql mysql 
shell> cd /usr/local
```

Untars the mariaDB binaries into which directory you choose.

```
shell> tar zxvf /usr/local/mysql/mysql-VERSION-OS.tar.gz
```

Created a symbolic link.

```
shell> ln -s /usr/local/mysql/mysql-VERSION-OS mysql 

shell> cd mysql
```

Recursively changes ownership to the user/group.

```
shell> chown -R mysql . 
shell> chgrp -R mysql .
```

Runs the mysql install db.

```
shell> scripts/mysql_install_db --user=mysql 
shell> chown -R root . 
shell> chown -R mysql data
```

Makes a copy of the my.cnf file to put into the etc folder

```
shell> cp support-files/my-medium.cnf /etc/my.cnf 
shell> bin/mysqld_safe --user=mysql &
```

Makes a copy of the server file to the init.d file which allows it to start automatically

```
shell> cp support-files/mysql.server /etc/init.d/mysql.server
```

Running my my_secure_installation script

```
 ./mysql_secure_installation --basedir=/usr/local/mysql/mariadb-5.5.34-linux-x86_64
```

I then closed the terminal and reopened, did:

```
ps -ef | grep mysql
```

to check the mysqld server was running (it was).

So I have done the above steps, I try and enter:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

and I receive the error

```
bash: mysql: command not found.
```

Any ideas why I cannot access it?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `mysql` in your path? `/usr/local/mysql` probably isn't by default

Comment: Yes the path in which i untared the binaries is /usr/local/mysql

Comment: try: `which mysql`. If that doesn't report anything, then the binaries aren't in your shell's path.

Comment: ah it bring the error: /usr/bin/which: no mysql in (/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin)  i'm not entirely sure what this means.

Comment: there you go. /usr/local/mysql is NOT in your shell's path. so you'll need to run `/usr/local/mysql/mysql`

Comment: Thank you, this gives me permission denied but I guess thats the way I set it up incorrectly. So If i wanted to start again from scratch, i would not make a directory in the name of 'mysql' in /usr/local/ it confused things.